# django: avoid "Unused variable" warning on get_or_create

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to avoid "Unused variable" warning on get_or_create method?

```
level,created= Level.objects.get_or_create( name='Alumnes x Classificar')
```

because I don't need to read `created` variable, IDE show a warning about this.

I know that a trivial solutions i to use variable, some thing like: `if create: pass`
But I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

See you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One “standard” way of doing this is to use the `_` variable:

```
level, _ = Level.objects.get_or_create(…)
```

`_` is a “real variable” (insomuch as you can read from and write to it), but it's generally understood to mean “ignored”.

Comment: This solutions seems more elegant than put a subindex. I will try with this.

Comment: but I would consider it a bad practice because in Django `_` is mostly used as var for translatable strings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation . I'm using the `# nopa` at the end of the line

Answer (score 3):

You could only capture the level by doing:

```
level = Level.objects.get_or_create( name='Alumnes x Classificar')[0]
```